# android:exported needs to be explicitly specified after add SonarQube in build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, sonarqube

I created a simple Hello World project in Android Studio as an example in Jenkins pipeline, it works but I want add SonarQube analysis, so I add follow lines in build.gradle as documentation shows (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
          url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.3"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I can build using `./gradle build` without problems, but when I execute `./gradlew sonarqube` I get following error:

```
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined
```

I investigated and checked if in my `/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` has `android:exported="true or false"` and it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.holapromad">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HolaPromad">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Is a bug or something? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's your case too: in my project the issue was caused by the the AndroidTest variant of the Manifest merger task which used a dated version of the `androidx.test.ext:junit` library.

Just update this library to the latest version (currently 1.1.3) into my app build.gradle file, solved the issue.

Comment: Updating from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3 solved the issue for me too

Answer (score 0):

Go To `build.gradle`

change your `classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.10'`

or any version  to

`classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.13.4'`